# Returning clause fails (postgres 9.3, jdbc)

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have looked at several link to retrieve the id with an insert using java, and I thought I would use the RETURNING clause.

my code:

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory", "postgres","root");
String sql = "INSERT INTO main (nom_fichier, adate, mdate, cdate, size, chunknumber)"
                + " VALUES ('test',450,450,450,450,5)"
                + " Returning id"
                + ";";
Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
int rowNumber = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: a result was returned when none was expected.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:339)
    at fr.infotel.postgre.TestPostgre.main(TestPostgre.java:25)
```

I also tried to use the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` (withouth Returning clause) without success (I had nothing in the result set).

First Question: I would like to make the RETURNING statement work, as my request works in psql

Second Question: If the first is not possible, how can I have the same result

I am using postgres 9.3 with the postgres9.3.jdbc3 jar.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you use `ResultSet` obj? I think `ResultSet` would be fine, try this.

Comment: ok, that was that simple... It has been 3 hours since I have this problem ...
thank you @AtaurRahmanMunna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ResultSet` object instead of  `rowNumber`

```
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

your query result now in `resultSet` variable.

Comment: How should that work? The `executeUpdate` method always returns an integer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

Comment: @EthanLeroy, My bad. Somehow i made the mistake. `executeQuery` return `ResultSet` object. I already update my answer. Thanks for the nice catch.